# Firefox React developer tools stopped working

Tags: reactjs, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I've been using the React developer tools extension in Firefox for some time, they're great. But yesterday the tools stopped working. The Components tab is available, but it doesn't show any content - my React component tree is simply missing, the pane is blank.

I've tried uninstalling the extension, closing Firefox, and reinstalling the extension.

I've tried rebooting my machine.

I've checked the Components tab settings, everything looks OK.

I've tried reverting to an old version of my project, back when the Developer tools definitely worked.

Has anybody got any ideas? There's no error, and I can't think of any way to investigate what's causing the problem. I haven't found anything by web searching.

And I can't switch to Chrome, because the tools won't install on Chrome under Linux!

OS: Linux mint Cinnamon

Firefox version: 63.0.3 (64 bit)

Comment: Just a note: JavaScript errors of the browser itself or any installed extensions are logged to the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), which can be opened via Ctrl+Shift+J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew, got it working again! I'm posting what worked for me in case it helps anybody else.

I completely uninstalled Firefox and reinstalled it following these instructions:

https://www.fosslinux.com/13881/how-to-clean-uninstall-and-reinstall-firefox-in-ubuntu.htm

Then re-added the Developer Tools extension, and it is now working. Firefox is now at version 69.0.